# How to obtain raw field value from db table in a view?

Tags: database, views

In Views 2 I am rewriting a field to generate a link that has arguments appended.

One of those fields is referenced as `[field_name_value]` but outputs 'public' (and translated) value of the field.  In the database the value is stored as `0` or `1` but it outputs `No` or `Yes` respectively.  The `No`/`Yes` must be coming from the content type template which provides a pair of radio buttons, where 'No' is 0 and 'Yes' is 1.

Is there any way to obtain the raw database (0 or 1) value? Thanks.

Comment: sounds like something in the widget/format is getting in your way.  I don't have v2 up anywhere anymore to play with this, but check into the formatting of the field at the very end of the field configuration screen .

Answer (score 1):

One of the last things Views does when it renders a view is to process all the fields raw data and format them according to settings, then theme according to the default or your own custom views templates.

So, if the 'Output format' options in field's settings on the view don't provide what you need, you can get the raw values - before formatting & theming - like so:

1. Install [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) so you can run code from within views fields, arguments etc.
2. Check the "Exclude from display" option on the fields you want 'raw' to stop them appearing in the output, but still ensure they're in the view data.
3. Add one "Global: PHP" field for each field for each hidden field.
4. In the "Output code" at the bottom of the field settings on the new Views PHP field, add something along the lines of `print $row->field_you_want_raw`.

Since you've got full PHP in these new fields you can format, tweak and merge any raw field data you need.

Comment: Thanks Jim, Sounds like it will work.  I did install views_php and in my fields area defined the needed field with "do not display" checked.  Then further down the list added a Global-PHP field with the output area defined as:

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what Jim Kirkpatrick said but at step 4 note the following changes.

- When inserting values in **Output code** you must enclose them in
- You can use a combination to display node information use **print $row->created;**
- To display database information use

  **print $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_YOURFIELD['und'][0]['value'];**

The module (7.x-1.x-dev) does not currently work as the documentation says or as you would expect.

Please refer to the following thread and comment for updates and a good example of how to figure out how to construct the code to print out your values. 
http://drupal.org/node/1061388#comment-4943984